# Proper formatting of R help pages in eldoc-doc-buffer using eglot

Tags: ess, r, eldoc, eglot

I am using `eglot` with `R` and `ESS`. If I have the following R script, with `eglot` enabled (saved as `test.R`:

```
lm
```

And I place my cursor on `lm` then a temporary `eldoc-buffer` pops showing the first few rows of the help page for the `lm` function. See the screenshot.

[image]

In the screenshot, you see that it says `<div class="container">` and if I open the `eldoc-doc-buffer`, I get the following

[image]

In contrast, VS Code, formats this nicely, see below.

[image]
[image]

I don't care to have a popup-ui, just that the help page is better rendered. Does anyone have any packages to look into or configurations to try?

Answer (score 0):

just encountered the same problem when setting up `eglot`. For me `options("languageserver.rich_documentation" = F)` (which I found at https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver#settings) improves rendering in emacs (by not using markdown).

Comment: Hi! How did you include this configuration into Eglot itself? I know the server has this variable `eglot-workspace-configuration` to include those configs into the server, but I don't know how to set it.

Comment: I was setting it in my .Rprofile file; just pasted `options("languageserver.rich_documentation" = F)` there. I'm not using eglot at the moment though, so not sure if things have changed or if there are other ways to configure it.